# OpenGeo displays layer in OpenLayers, but not GeoExplorer?

Tags: openlayers-2, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

My test server updated today I think it was a PHP update, and since then I can no longer view data in GeoExplorer, only OpenLayers. The GeoExplorer can not see my local server.

Any hints?

Update: Firebug says:

```
   TypeError: e is undefined
...&&!Ext.isEmpty(f.title)&&(e.set("title",f.title),a.setValue(e.get(d))):c.remove(...

 GeoExplorer.js (line 1535)
```

Another error from Geoexplorer:

```
Non-existing source 'local' referenced in layer config.
```

Further information from the GeoServer log:

```
org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleLayer(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:899)
    ... 87 more
2013-07-19 13:16:12,458 INFO [geoserver.wms] - Request: getServiceInfo

2013-07-19 13:16:12,459 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@1965791
```

Comment: Unlikely that a PHP update causes this. Looks like WMS GetCapabilities is broken. Try to open http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities in a browser and scan the response for error messages.

Comment: @ahocevar It only seems to do this occasionally, where the local server wont load, It happened a few days back, I ended up making a new test server and everything worked. I have hardly touched geoserver all I have done is linked to my postGIS, and created a style. Turned it off yesterday, and today I get the error I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to a faulty change in SLD, even though the style worked, when I restarted the server this is when the geoexplorer issues arise. Solution, delete the style, and replace with the default SLD cookbook style.